# Sections, Transversals and Quotient Maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, category-theory

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28category_theory%29) I read:

> Given a quotient space $\bar X$ with quotient map $\pi\colon X \to \bar X$, a section of $\pi $ is called a transversal.

I asked myself how such sections are possible. It must be a map $f$ such that $f\circ \pi = \operatorname{id}_X$, or $x \mapsto [x] \mapsto x$. But how could such a map from $\bar X$ to $X$ be realized? The map could select some $x$ from every equvalence class, but how does it know what $x$ was fed into the equivalence class? So I guess such a section is just possible when the equivalence classes are singletons, i.e. $[x] = \{x\}$, which would be quite trivial. Does anybody know examples of sections of quotient maps?

Comment: The axiom of choice.

Comment: Ah, I confused section with left-inverse, actually a section is a right-inverse and then I understand it. So for the quotient map a function $f:\bar X \to X$ with $\pi \circ f = \operatorname{id}_{\bar X}$ is searched, and this could be easily established, see the examples of Berci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. For example consider $\pi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_m$, then a section can be given by $[a]\mapsto (a\,\rm{mod}\, m)$, where $(a\,\rm{mod}\, m)$ is the *remainder* modulo $m$, in the set $\{0,1,2,..,m-1\}$.

This works in the category $\Bbb{Set}$ of sets.

But for example, in the category $\Bbb{Mod}_R$ *modules* over a (commutative) ring $R$, having a section of $A\to A/B\ $ (where $B$ is a submodule of $A$) means exactly that there is a $C\le A$ submodule such that $A= B\oplus C$.

Other trivial example that works in most concrete category with direct products, is the projection $\pi:A\times B\to A$, then pick a suitable element $b\in B$ such that the section $a\mapsto (a,b)$ is in the given category..